# Count number of 1's from right to left, stopping at the first 0

Tags: r, count, conditional-statements

I want to count the number of 1's that occur from RIGHT to LEFT across multiple columns, which stops when encountering the first 0.

Example DF:

```
df<-data.frame(replicate(7,sample(0:1,30,rep=T)))
colnames(df)<-seq(1950,2010,10)
```

I've manually entered the desired result here under a new column "condition" as an example:

[image]

Thanks in advance for your help,

Cai

Comment: Use `set.seed(..)` to make your example reproducable.

Comment: Thanks @jogo, will do next time, though not absolutely necessary here.

Comment: Btw, when you have a binary data set like this, it will be much faster to work with matrices instead of data.frames.

Comment: Thanks @DavidArenburg - I'll bear this in mind next time I set up an example dataset!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a fully vectorized attempt

```
indx <- rowSums(df) == ncol(df) # Per Jaaps comment
df$condition <- ncol(df) - max.col(-df, ties = "last")
df$condition[indx] <- ncol(df) - 1
```

This is basically finds the first zero from the right and counts how many columns were before that (which are basically the `1`s in a binary data)

**EDIT**

Had to add handling for the special case when all the rows are ones

Comment: I think you need to add `df$condition[rowSums(df==1)==7] <- 7` because when all numbers in a row are `1`, you get `0` while the desired output is `7`.

Comment: Good catch @Jaap, had to add some extra steps there

Answer (score 1):

```
df$condition <- apply(df, 1, function(x) {
  y <- rev(x)
  sum(cumprod(y))
})
```

Comment: similarly, `apply(df[length(df):1], 1, function(x) sum(cummin(x) == 1))`

Answer (score 0):

We can loop through the rows, use `rle`

```
df$condition <- apply(df, 1, function(x) {x1 <- rle(x)
      x2 <- tail(x1$lengths, 1)[tail(x1$values, 1)==1]
      if(length(x2)==0) 0 else x2})
```

---

Or another option is `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
v1 <- str_extract(do.call(paste0, df), "1+$")
d$condition <- ifelse(is.na(v1), 0, nchar(v1))
```

---

Or with a slightly more efficient `stringi`

```
library(stringi)
v1 <- stri_count(stri_extract(do.call(paste0, df), regex = "1+$"), regex = ".")
v1[is.na(v1)] <- 0
df$condition <- v1
```

---

Or with a more compact option

```
stri_count(do.call(paste0, df), regex = '(?=1+$)')
```

Comment: your second solution is the fastest so far

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper I seriously doubt that. Did you do proper benchmarks? Text processing can't be faster than a vectorized numeric operation as provided by David.

Comment: @Roland I did, David's solution is the slowest, on par with akrun's first

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Add the benchmark to your answer. I suspect you've benchmarked with OP's tiny example where speed differences aren't really relevant.

Comment: indeed, actually I had benchmarked with a smaller one initially, now just added the benchmark for OP's example, and will add with a much bigger one as well, I'll add the benchmark with

Comment: See my answer, you're right for bigger a bigger df it's much faster

Answer (score 0):

[Edit: now works]

Try this

```
df$condition <-  apply(df,1,function(x){x<- rev(x);m <- match(0,x)[1]; if (is.na(m)) sum(x) else sum(x[1:m])})
```

we're matching the first 0, then summing up until this element.
If there's no zero we sum the full row

---

Here's a benchmark of all solutions :

```
library(stringr)
microbenchmark(
Moody_Mudskipper =  apply(df,1,function(x){x<- rev(x);m <- match(0,x)[1]; if (is.na(m)) sum(x) else sum(x[1:m])}),
akrun =  apply(df, 1, function(x) {x1 <- rle(x)
                                          x2 <- tail(x1$lengths, 1)[tail(x1$values, 1)==1]
                                          if(length(x2)==0) 0 else x2}),
akrun2 = str_count(do.call(paste0, df), "[1]+$"),
roland = apply(df, 1, function(x) {y <- rev(x);sum(y * cumprod(y != 0L))}),
David_Arenburg  = ncol(df) - max.col(-df, ties = "last"),
times = 10)

# Unit: microseconds
#                     expr      min       lq      mean   median       uq      max neval
#         Moody_Mudskipper 1437.948 1480.417 1677.1929 1536.159 1597.209 3009.320    10
#                    akrun 6985.174 7121.078 7718.2696 7691.053 7856.862 9289.146    10
#                   akrun2 1101.731 1188.793 1290.8971 1226.486 1343.099 1790.091    10
#                   akrun3  693.315  791.703  830.3507  820.371  884.782 1030.240    10
#                   roland 1197.995 1270.901 1708.5143 1332.305 1727.802 4568.660    10
#           David_Arenburg 2845.459 3060.638 3406.3747 3167.519 3495.950 5408.494    10
# David_Arenburg_corrected 3243.964 3341.644 3757.6330 3384.645 4195.635 4943.099    10
```

For a bigger example David's solution is indeed the fastest, as said in the chosen solution's comments:

```
df<-data.frame(replicate(7,sample(0:1,1000,rep=T)))

# Unit: milliseconds
#                     expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
#         Moody_Mudskipper  31.324456  32.155089  34.168533  32.827345  33.848560  44.952570    10
#                    akrun 225.592061 229.055097 238.307506 234.761584 241.266853 271.000470    10
#                   akrun2  28.779824  29.261499  33.316700  30.118144  38.026145  46.711869    10
#                   akrun3  14.184466  14.334879  15.528201  14.633227  17.237317  18.763742    10
#                   roland  27.946005  28.341680  29.328530  28.497224  29.760516  33.692485    10
#           David_Arenburg   3.149823   3.282187   3.630118   3.455427   3.727762   5.240031    10
# David_Arenburg_corrected   3.464098   3.534527   4.103335   3.833937   4.187141   6.165159    10
```